# Is it bad practice to place other objects on the class namespace?

Tags: python, oop

I have a bunch of shards (databases) that I'm querying for data, and then I need to create a manifest file for `S3`.  Would it be bad practice to put the manifest object at the class level like so:

```
class Shard(mu.PrettyStr):
    # Tracks files on a class level for manifest creation.
    manifest = aws.S3Manifest()
```

And then manipulate it like so:

```
Shard.manifest.add_record(
            s3_destination=s3.get_full_destination()
        )
```

or

```
cu.Shard.manifest.create_manifest()
```

Comment: Why not just put it at the module level? This isn't java

Comment: Hmm good idea, hadn't considered that.  I think it was because one of my methods calls it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making it a class instance means that that the manifest class will be instantiated when `Shard` is defined, not when it is instantiated. If that's OK, then what you've done is fine.

If you would rather defer this until there's at least one instance of your class, define it as `None` on the class and then instantiate it in `Shard.__init__()` if the attribute is not `None`.

Comment: Yep no worries there.